# WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists in python

Tags: python, file

i  tried with bellow mentioned code just to rename some files. but this same code works good in linux but not in windows. 
CODE

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from os import listdir
import os
from os.path import isfile, join
mypath = 'D:\\Hadoo'
path = 'D:\\Hadoo'
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath, f))]
Existing = []
repeated = []
for a in onlyfiles:
    f = a.index('}')
    b = a[f + 1:]
    Existing.append(b)
    os.rename(os.path.join(mypath, a), os.path.join(path, b))
```

InLinux input:
`file{}a1.txt , file{}a2.txt`
InLinux output:
`a1.txt , a2.txt`

but same not happening in Windows . it through following error:

```
>python filer.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "filer.py", line 16, in <module>
os.rename(os.path.join(mypath, a), os.path.join(path, b))
WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists
```

Comment: Can you remove all the scanning from your example? It would reduce the code and make it clearer. Effectively, the important part is what are the parameters to `os.rename()` and what is the according state in the filesystem at that time?

Comment: Check the destination folder for same name files..

Comment: please read it [os.rename](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.rename). U see, that rename raise a OSError on windows, if dst file already exists. And on linux  it will be replaced. u have may be run the program more times and the dst files exist already. U should delete them or check for the files before

Comment: Thanks for every one. i just missed out some similar file in that folder location. that caused this problem